# SVG radial progress bar doesn't rotate in Safari, any workarounds?

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, css-transforms

I am following this tutorial: https://codepen.io/xgad/post/svg-radial-progress-meters

Everything looks good in all browsers until the last step, where we add `rotate(-90deg)` to make the progress start from the top instead of from the right side. That seems to work in all browsers but Safari, on macOS (Safari 10.0.1) and iOS (10.1).

1. Is it a bug in Safari? I couldn't find anything about it.
2. Are there any (easy) workarounds?

Comment: The link you posted works on my iPhone safari. I.E. It rotates.

Comment: @AllDani So the last Codepen on that page looks like this? http://imgur.com/a/VAHK2

Comment: Hard to say. Since it rotates, it's not comparable to an image.

Comment: @AllDani Huh? Can you send me a screenshot? I don't understand what you mean at all. :S The last codepen is not animated, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Can't repro on 9.1.3 (mavericks)

Comment: http://codepen.io/xgad/pen/EKJojM this rotates for me on iphone safari

Comment: @AllDani I think you're confusing rotation with animation. I'm not talking about the progress animating, I'm talking about the SVG circle not being affected at all by the fixed `transform: rotate` value. Please look at the last codepen on the page and compare it with the screenshot I sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug (regression) in Safari, the iOS version of which was reported here: https://openradar.appspot.com/27763347. The bug can since be reproduced on Safari 10 for macOS as well.

An easy workaround is to rotate by -89.9deg instead of -90deg. The difference is barely noticeable.